# How to compile a simple swig-python library on macOS?

Tags: python, c++, swig

Could somebody help me identify why I'm getting a segfault with this very simple swig-python library on macos? I don't have any problems on the other platforms but macOS is being difficult.

```
// Example.h
#ifndef Example
#define Example

#include <vector>

std::vector<int> getVofI();

#endif
```

```
// Example.cpp
#include "Example.h"

std::vector<int> getVofI(){
    return std::vector<int>({1, 2, 3});
}
```

```
// Example.i
%module Example

%{
    #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT

    #include <vector>

    #include "Example.h"


%}
%include "std_vector.h"
%include "Example.h"
```

Now to build:

```
swig -c++ -python Example.i # make Example_wrap.cxx
#compile both our C++ files
g++ -O2 -fPIC  -std=c++17 -I/Users/Ciaranwelsh/miniconda3/envs/py39/include/python3.9 -c Example.h Example.cpp 
g++ -O2 -fPIC  -std=c++17 -I/Users/Ciaranwelsh/miniconda3/envs/py39/include/python3.9 -c Example_wrap.cxx
# and link
clang++ -std=c++17 -L/Users/Ciaranwelsh/miniconda3/envs/py39/lib -lpython3.9 -dynamiclib Example.o Example_wrap.o -o _Example.so
```

However in Python I get a segfault.

```
In [1]: import _Example
Segmentation fault: 11
```